Error downloading Bitbucket repo with Docker and Python
Objective:
Download a repository from Bitbucket from a requirements.txt file, executing the installation via Docker.
Example of the app:
Docker file executes "pip install requirements.txt" > Pip installs in the environment the repository from Bitbucket.

The problem appears when downloading the repository: the id_rsa key is not recognized.
I followed these steps:

Add private key to the Docker image.
Add the public key to the Workspace > Settings > SSH-keys section.

These are the files:
Dockerfile:
FROM python:X
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [“/bin/bash”,“/app/start.sh” ]

Requirements.txt:
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/company/repo_name.git@version

But I receive this error:
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Does anyone know how to fix it? (the repository exists and the URL is correct)
I have tried downloading the repository with the same keys and it works fine (the line ssh -T... displays the following message:
authenticated via ssh key.
You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled


since many organizations do not enable ssh, can u try with https instead?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have updated the post, let me know if it is better!
And unfortunately no, I can not use HTTPS, I have to use only SSH

How precisely do you think you're getting your SSH keys into the container for authentication? And how do you even build the image? Those are important parts that are missing from your Q, which you can [edit] to fix that. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].
